# Counting letters and printing an array of numbers with windows api

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, masm

I have an user input string, which was lowercased and all special characters removed `target2` and I want to count how many times each letter appears on the string, and then print the array with 26 letters.  However, it prints just a blank line.  Is the error when I add to the array? when I print from the array, or both?

If I watch  `letterArray`, it says `1 '\x1'` What does that mean?

`lettersArray byte 26 dup(0)`

```
countingLetters proc
  ; clear esi and edi
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, 0

  charloop
    mov al, target2[esi]               ; Get a character from the string
    cmp al, 97                   ; Check if its not a letter
    jb printloop                ; If bellow, print
    sub eax, 97                  ; so that 'a' = 0, 'z' = 26.
    mov dl, lettersArray[eax]
    inc dl
    mov lettersArray[eax], dl
    inc esi
    jmp charloop                ; repeat


    printloop:
    mov bl, lettersArray[edx * type lettersArray]
    add bl, 48
    push edx
    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, ebx, 4, bytesWritten, 0
    pop edx
    inc edx
    cmp edx, 25                 ;Are we done?
    ja  done                    ;if yes
    jmp printloop               ; Repeat
  done:
  ret 
countingLetters endp
```

This should count the appearances of each letter and print an array with 26 elements, i.e: 00102000000000[etc]

Comment: `1 '\x1'` is just the output of a debugger telling you the value is 1 decimal (and `\x1` just means the hex value)

Comment: In printloop you don't set EDX before using it in the instruction `mov bl, lettersArray[edx * type lettersArray]`

Comment: `invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, ebx, 4, bytesWritten, 0` - WriteConsoleA takes pointers to data, not values so you can't just pass the value in EBX. You would need to store the value in register_BL_ to a memory location (a byte variable) and pass the address of that variable.

Comment: Yes, that was it, it now works as intended.  Than you!  I found a good reading here about addressing modes: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html